# Do I need to manually take my luggage from one plane to the next?

Tags: air-travel, luggage, pegasus-airlines

I'm flying to Izmir, Turkey, in a few weeks, but I don't know anything about how flying works.

I have booked a ticket with Pegasus airlines, and fly:

1. From Schiphol (NL) to Istanbul (TK)
2. I have a 1 hour wait in Istanbul
3. Fly from Istanbul to Izmir

So now I wonder if I need to manually retrieve my luggage from the Schiphol-Istanbul plane and bring it somewhere to be put on the Istanbul-Izmir plane?

Because I only have 1 hour in between, I wonder if I will have enough time to handle transferring the luggage?

Comment: @calchas thanks for your answer. Won't 1 hour be a bit short in that case?

Comment: the layover is long enough for you to catch your next plane, as always, if you feel time will be short, tell the flight attendant about your next flight; they might rush you out of the plane and tell the other plane to wait for you (if timing is really short)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your luggage will be checked in all the way. You don't need to collect it as you will be in transit, and your luggage will be in a secured area.

You will (of course) have to carry your carry-on luggage with you to the next plane.